# How to investigate latency of a webserver running wordpress

Tags: wordpress, nginx

[image]

How to investigate the 2.95s latency on the very first response from VPS????

My VPS (2 Core, 4 GB RAM, 100 GB HDD) is hosted on a reputed service.

My server has centos 6.5, nginx 1.4.4, php 5.4.23, mysql 5.5.35, wordpress 3.7 with W3 Total Cache. Caching seems to work. Nginx conf enabled Gzip for all media.

When I look through chrome dev tools in network panel, the very first GET request made is getting response in around 2.9 seconds. In other words, time taken for html generation + network travel is 2.9 seconds.

Then starting from the first response, the whole site is getting loaded in next 2.2 seconds - taking the total time to 5.x seconds.

Test php page that queries db and renders the page is having under 70 milliseconds latency in the first step.

Whats the scope for improvement other than increasing CPU cores? Is it possible to tune up the server with some settings or for the amount of given page complexity (theme, etc) this is it and nothing can be done other than hardware addition?

Disk IP perf: DD command results 1.1 GB copied, 3.5 - 6 s, 180 - 300 MB/s

PS: I am aware of other SO questions, most of them recommend some cache plugin, apache mod setting, etc, I am posting this after I have spent enough time digging through them.

Comment: How do you know your CPU is the problem? It could be disk IO, network issues, or plenty of other culprits.

Comment: @ChrisHayes I don't know whether its CPU related. What do you mean by network issues? I will post disk IO stats shortly

Comment: @ChrisHayes disk io is averaging 200 mb/s (dd command several times), you mentioned network issues can you tip me with what should I look for?

Comment: Shut off W3 Total Cache and see if that helps. Also if you have APC OptiCache turn that off/on to see if its interfering. APC has some issues on some versions of CentOS 6 but I don't remember which version.

Answer (score 0):

xDebug will show you, per script, how much time your server spends executing it http://xdebug.org/docs/profiler